# Htaccess Redirection- I want to redirect to URL when my query string is equal to -this-is-test1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect to URL when my query string is equal to `-this-is-test1`

```
Redirect /search/product/basecamp?-this-is-test1 https://www.some-example.com/search/product/result-this-is-test1
```

Note: There is the only value not any key in the query string.

Comment: Hi, could you please do let us know how our solutions went please in respective answers, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, make sure you clear your browser cache after placing these rules into yout .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  \s/(search/product)/basecamp\?(-this-is-test1)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/result%2? [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match query string in `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives.
You may use this rule based on `mod_rewrite` module:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (-this-is-test1) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(search/product)/basecamp/?$ /$1/result%1? [NE,L,R=301,NC]
```

`?` at the end of target will strip any query string.

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)